# Edit one line in #each block

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I have template:

```
{{#each action_log}}
  <div>
     {{Name}}

     {{#if editing_score}}
        <input type="text" id="set_score" parm="{{_id}}" value="" />
     {{else}}
        <div class="score" id="{{_id}}">{{Score}} .</div>   
     {{/if}}

   </div>
{{/each}}
```

And I have a javascript code:

```
Session.set('editing_score', false);

Template.today_list.editing_score = function() {
    return Session.equals('editing_score', true);
  };

Template.today_list.events({
 'click .score': function(e, t) {
      Session.set('editing_score', true);      
      Session.set('editing_score_id', e.target.id);
      Meteor.flush();
    }
});
```

So, user can see list of actions, want to click on one of them and edit some value.  But now, if user click on the action, the code display textboxes for all actions.

How can I display a textbox only for one action ?

I have action id in Session:

```
Session.set('editing_score_id', e.target.id);
```

But I can not do something like this:

```
{{#if editing_score && editing_score_id == _id}}
```

or

```
{{#if editing_score(_id)}}
```

What is the best way to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your template:

```
{{#if editing_score id}}
```

With your helper:

```
Template.today_list.editing_score = function(id) {
  return Session.equals('editing_score_id', id);
};
```

However, I would refactor a bit so that you only have one Session variable — no need for two.

Also, your 'click .score' passes context, so you can id from `this` — which I find is more reliable than mucking around with the event that you are passing in.